# Mockito tests cases for file input stream

Tags: mockito

In a method i am doing some operations with the fileinputstream. Now i want to write the mockito test cases for the fileinputstream so how write for this scenario? Actually the file is reading from the server so i can not create the dummy file in local.  For this scenario i have to write the mockito test cases with out using the power mockito and whenNew condition

I have tried different approaches by mocking the file and fileinput stream and different ways but i am getting file not found exception

Comment: `FileInputStream extends InputStream`. Other sub class are `ByteArrayInputStream` and `StringBufferInputStream`. Change your code to use the interface ("implement to an interface, not an implementation"), then pass one of the in-memory input streams to your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.